# Unable to type anything inside an input text box, after putting a jquery code for keycode trapping

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML form with YES or NO button. My requirement is to press "Y" or "N" keys and to invoke corresponding button without any focus.I have written a jQuery and on pressing 'Y' or 'N' it is invoking correct button and is working as expected  but here is one glitch.

My input text box are not able to accept text or in other words keys are not working.

my HTML code is :

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>UserName:</td> <td><input type="text" id="uname"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Password:</td> <td><input type="text" id="pswd"> </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br><br>
<table  cellspacing="20">   
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" id="yes" >YES</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <td><button type="button" id="no"  >NO</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my jquery is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();  

        if (e.which == 89) {
            alert("Y");
        }

        if (e.which == 78) {
            alert("N");
        }
    });
});
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: show us a not-working demo...

Comment: Simply remove `e.preventDefault();` from `keydown` event.

Comment: It is normal SO etiquette to accept the earliest answer when several are the same. Hover the answer date to see exactly when they were posted (although it is blatantly obvious in this case) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code. you just need to remove or comment `e.preventDefault();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {   
          

        if (e.which == 89) {
            alert("Y");
        }

        if (e.which == 78) {
            alert("N");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>UserName:</td> <td><input type="text" id="uname"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Password:</td> <td><input type="text" id="pswd"> </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br><br>
<table  cellspacing="20">   
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" id="yes" >YES</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <td><button type="button" id="no"  >NO</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.preventDefault()` will stop all keys from working!

Just remove that :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `e.preventDefault();` from `keydown` event.

Answer (score 0):

You use `e.preventDefault();` which causes the browser to not send keypress to input. You can add a condition to check if any input field has focus and if it has then don't run code inside this callback.